# pgfplots: fill the volume under a 3d surface

Tags: pgfplots

I have a very simple 3d graph.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[view={60}{20},
%axis equal image=true,
xlabel=$X(T)$, ylabel={$D(T)$}, zlabel={$V(T)$},
zmin=0
]
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,z buffer=sort,
samples=30,domain=0:100,y domain=0:100]
{x+y}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This code draws a surface. What I would like to see is the volume under the surface to be colored. Moreover I would like to label in some way the filled volume as "defaulted".
I went through all the pages of the manual but could not find any solution. 
Does someone know how to do it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Could you explain what do you really mean when you say *filled volume*. May be an image or something. I want to see the output you are looking for.

Comment: I am looking for this kind of output:

\addplot3[...]
{x+y}; 

http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/752/filled.jpg

Comment: You will need to provide something like `\fill[red] (axis cs:0,0,0) -- (axis cs:100,0,100);` manually after your `surf` plot (or add feature requests for such a plot type - which might be a "waterfall plot"?).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I only read Christian Feuersänger's comment after putting together exactly what he recommends; so here's what you could do, but you'll need to manually specify points at the edge, which will be quite complicated for curved surfaces:

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={60}{20},
%axis equal image=true,
xlabel=$X(T)$, ylabel={$D(T)$}, zlabel={$V(T)$},
zmin=0
]
\fill[opacity=0.5,red] (axis cs: 0,0,0) -- (axis cs: 100,0,100) -- (axis cs: 100,0,0) -- cycle;
\fill[opacity=0.5,yellow] (axis cs: 0,0,0) -- (axis cs: 0,100,100) -- (axis cs: 0,100,0) -- cycle;
\fill[opacity=0.5,green] (axis cs: 100,0,100) -- (axis cs: 100,100,200) -- (axis cs: 100,100,0) -- (axis cs: 100,0,0) -- cycle;
\fill[opacity=0.5,blue] (axis cs: 0,100,100) -- (axis cs: 100,100,200) -- (axis cs: 100,100,0) -- (axis cs: 0,100,0) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,z buffer=sort,samples=30,domain=0:100,y domain=0:100]{x+y}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** You can also fake the color gradient (in this simple example):

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[   view={60}{20},
    xlabel=$X(T)$,
    ylabel={$D(T)$},
    zlabel={$V(T)$},
    zmin=0,
]
\fill[opacity=1,left color=blue, right color=yellow] (axis cs: 0,0,0) -- (axis cs: 100,0,100) -- (axis cs: 100,0,0) -- cycle;
\fill[opacity=1,bottom color=yellow, top color=red] (axis cs: 100,0,100) -- (axis cs: 100,100,200) -- (axis cs: 100,100,0) -- (axis cs: 100,0,0) -- cycle;
\addplot3[surf,shader=flat,z buffer=sort,samples=30,domain=0:100,y domain=0:100]{x+y}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I suspect the `red` area has to be filled after the `yellow` one.

Comment: Probably with `opacity=1`. But here (`opacity=0.5`) it really does not matter ;)